# infinite loop keeps my page loading

Tags: php

I have a function that is supposed to be an infinite function, but when I start it it keeps loading. in this case he keeps going around 70-79 seconds while I have specified 21 in `set_time_limit`.

When I start it doesn't do anything and when those 75 seconds are done it suddenly display 8 times the date difference. all at once. I want it to display my text every 1 second and without lagging for 1 hour long
all my values below are lower then the numbers I said above because I thought that 1 second would maybe to fast but it still lags for 10 seconds

```
set_time_limit (21);
// 21 seconds until its done should become an hour later
// this was to test 
$x=1;
$startTime = time();
$timeout = 10;   //timeout in seconds
for ($i=0;;$i++)
{
   if(time() > $startTime + ($x * $timeout)) {

     $x++;
     $today=date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
     echo "it's now: ". $today . "</br>";
     $newyear = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, 01, 01, 2013));
     $difference=get_datediff_string($vandaag,$nieuwjaar); 
     // get_datediff_string() is defined somewhere below,
     // but wasn't worth to show it.
     echo "it is $difference untill newyear"; 

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by implicit buffering. It might be on the server side (in which case just calling `flush()` after `echo` should fix it), or it might be on the browser (in which case you're out of luck).

This kind of script really should be a console program anyway, I really don't see the point of what you're doing in a browser context.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `usleep` to pause the script? And why is your aim an hour? It seems to me that you should rather do this in JavaScript..

```
<?php
$x=1;
$startTime = time();
$timeout = 10;   //timeout in seconds
for ($i=0;;$i++)
{

   set_time_limit (10);
   usleep(1000);

   $x++;
   $today=date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
   echo "it's now: ". $today . "</br>";
   $newyear = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, 01, 01, 2013));
   $difference=get_datediff_string($vandaag,$nieuwjaar); // get_datediff_string() is defined somewhere below but wasn't worth to show it.
   echo "it is " . $difference . " untill newyear"; 
   flush();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the date is printed every $timeout seconds, consider using sleep($timeout) at the end of loop, so the loop won't run thousands of times between two dates print, causing your lag problems.

Finally i think that this script is unuseful in server side, if you want to show a countdown for new year, do it in javascript.